# Interaction term positive while components are negative?

Tags: regression

I am confused about the interpretation of my interaction term , I have been through similar questions but I am still not sure about the interpretation that I should give to my output .

[image]

So this is my model , Y  stands for earnings management , X1 = CSR , X2=CEO duality , as you can see both of the coefficients are negative CSR reduces earnings management manipulation and Duality in my sample reduces em as well  which is in line with the literature and confirm my hypothesis , but to my surprise my interaction term is positive and significant does that mean that CSR combined with duality increase EM ? Or that CEO duality moderates the effect of CSR on EM knowing that in papers that I've read, they only use" moderate "when the interaction term and the components are all negative .
Could you please help me ? I am supposed to comment my results but I don"t understand this .
Thank you

Comment: If the negative signs bother you, fit the model to `-csr`, `-dual`, and their interaction: now all the signs will be positive.

Comment: Thank you Whuber , actually it's part of my hypothesis so when I get a negative correlation between  both CSR and Duality , it is an expected  output , but the interaction term s positive , and this is what I find hard to understand !

Comment: I don't follow that, because the interaction term is unrelated to the correlation between those two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I'm going to call your variables $x_1$, $x_2$, and $y$.

$$
\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x_1 + \hat{\beta}_2x_2 + \hat{\beta}_3x_1x_2
$$

Take the (partial) derivatives.

$$
\dfrac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x_1} = \hat{\beta}_1 + \hat{\beta}_3x_2
$$

$$
\dfrac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial x_2} = \hat{\beta}_2 + \hat{\beta}_3x_1
$$

When the interaction term $\hat{\beta}_3$ is negative, it means that, as $x_2$ increases, the effect on $y$ of $x_1$ decreases, and as $x_1$ increases, the effect on $y$ of $x_2$ decreases.

Comment: Please do say if either or both of your predictor variables are categorical.

Comment: Dear Dave , thank you again for your answer , now my B3 is positive is that suggest that when X1 increases , "the effect of Y on X2 decreases" can I use this syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `csr` and `dual` are 0 or 1 indicators, what you seem to have is

- CSR tends to be associated with lower earnings management  (negative coefficient)
- CEO duality tends to be associated with lower earnings management to a greater extent (negative coefficient 4.4 times larger)
- having both is even more associated with lower earnings management, but it is not quite an additive effect (relatively smaller and positive coefficient, so adding the three together is more negative than either alone but not quite as much as just adding the two individual values)

Comment: Thank you for your reply , at least now I have a clear idea about coefficients , so if I understand the three variables together as the interaction term, CSR  and duality in the model decrease earnings management but this effect is more pronounced when we stick to a model with only  csr and duality as individual variables without using an interaction term . Please correct me if I am wrong . Thank you again !

Comment: You would get different coefficients if you did that, and you would need a reason for ignoring the interaction you have already observed.  Perhaps some cases of both CSR and CEO duality are examples where companies are just trying to look to good